# Vega: Use filter as input and dynamically change data URL

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega, vega-lite, elk

I am trying to create a `Vega` visualisation using an external URL and I want to construct the URL dynamically using some filters as input to the visualisation. My current Vega code is this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,

  "data": {
    "name": "table",
    "url":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aryak93/vega/master/data.json"
  },

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "tooltip",
      "value": {},
      "on": [
        {"events": "rect:mouseover", "update": "datum"},
        {"events": "rect:mouseout",  "update": "{}"}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "category"},
      "range": "width",
      "padding": 0.05,
      "round": true
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "amount"},
      "nice": true,
      "range": "height"
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    { "orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale" },
    { "orient": "left", "scale": "yscale" }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data":"table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "category"},
          "width": {"scale": "xscale", "band": 1},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "amount"},
          "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 0}
        },
        "update": {
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "red"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "bottom"},
          "fill": {"value": "#333"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "signal": "tooltip.category", "band": 0.5},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "signal": "tooltip.amount", "offset": -2},
          "text": {"signal": "tooltip.amount"},
          "fillOpacity": [
            {"test": "isNaN(tooltip.amount)", "value": 0},
            {"value": 1}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'm trying is to change the URL from `"url":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aryak93/vega/master/data.json"` to something like `"url":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aryak93/vega/master/data.json?projectName={projectName}"` and I am expecting the project name to be populated when a user sets the filter.

So far, I have struggled to find something relevant from the Vega and Vega lite documentations. Please let me know whether this'll be possible.

Comment: You posted this a few years agod, did you find ? I am looking for the same thing.